Relative homology of subsets of a surface
I've been reading a paper recently and it mentions a fact that I wasn't aware of before. The situation is as follows. Let $X$ be a non-compact, oriented surface and let $D, D'$ be relatively compact, connected open subsets of $X$. Suppose $\overline{D} \subset D'$, and that $X \setminus D$ and $X \setminus D'$ have no relatively compact connected components. The paper then claims that the long exact homology sequence (with integer coefficients) of the pair $(D', D)$ has the form
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  0 @>>> H_1(D) @>>> H_1(D') @>>> H_1(D', D) @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
That is, it becomes a short exact sequence. Why is this the case? The only hint of an explanation I can come up with is that the above conditions imply that $D$ is a retract of $D'$ which will hence give the sequence above. However, it is not clear to me that these conditions do indeed yield a retraction, or if this is a misleading guess on my part and there is another possible explanation.

Well, for starters $D$ cannot be a retract of $D'$ because it is not closed in $D'$.

I have a certain intuition here. It is enough to show that the induced map $i_:H_(D)\to H_*(D')$ is injective. If it is not then we can find a say polygon in $D$ that cannot be filled in $D$, but it can be filled in $D'$. This means that the interior of the polygon is not part of $D$. But it is part of $D'$, hence $X$. Which means that it is a part of a relatively compact (because bounded by the polygon) component of $X\backslash D$. I don't know how to formalize this intuition though.

Note that it suffices to show that $H_2(D', D) = 0$. We will deduce this
from more general considerations.
For a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ and an open set $U \subset M$, there is a general computation of $H_n(M, U)$ that goes as follows.
A reference for this material is Section 7 of Chapter VI of the book
Topology and Geometry by Bredon.
There is a covering map $\theta: \widetilde{M} \to M$
whose fiber over a point $x \in M$ is the local homology $H_n(M, M - \{ x \})$.
Then for any closed subset $A \subset M$,
there is a natural group morphism
$$
H_n(M, M - A) \to \Gamma_c(A, \theta),
$$
where $\Gamma_c(A, \theta)$ is the group of compactly-supported sections of $\theta$
over $A$.
Then, we have the following theorem:

Theorem (Bredon, Theorem 7.8, p.344):
Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ and $A \subset M$ be a closed subset. Then:
(a) $H_i(M, M-A) = 0$ for $i > n$,
(b) the map $H_n(M, M-A) \to \Gamma_c(A, \theta)$ is an isomorphism.

From this theorem we deduce:

Proposition: Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ and $U \subset M$
be an open set such that every component of $M-U$ is non-compact.
Then $H_n(M,U) = 0$.

Proof: Let $A = M-U$, which is a closed subset. By the theorem, we have
$$H_n(M,U) = H_n(M, M-A) \cong \Gamma_c(A, \theta)$$
Let $s \in \Gamma_c(A, \theta)$ and let $C$ be a connected component of $A$.
By assumption, $C$ is non-compact. Since $s$ is compactly-supported, we have $s(x) = 0$
for some $x \in C$.
But then $s \equiv 0$ over $C$ since $C$ is connected.
Since $C$ was arbitrary, this shows that $s \equiv 0$ over $A$.
We conclude that $\Gamma_c(A, \theta) = 0$. $\square$

Let's return now to the situation of the OP. We have the triple $(X, D', D)$.
Consider the following part of the long exact sequence of the triple:
$$
H_3(X,D') \to H_2(D', D) \to H_2(X,D)
$$
We have $H_3(X,D') = 0$ by part (a) of the theorem. Moreover, by the proposition, we have
$H_2(X,D) = 0$ since $X-D$ has no compact connected components.
Therefore, we conclude that $H_2(D', D) = 0$.
Remark: Note that many of the assumptions about $D$, $D'$ and $X$ that
were stated in the OP were not used in the previous argument.

Thanks for your answer! So I suppose this result turned out to be something quite deep (I haven't studied Bredon's book extensively). Could I ask about the other end of the long exact sequence? I would think that the map $H_0(D) \to H_0(D')$ is injective because $D$ and $D'$ are connected, but I'm not sure about formalising this idea.

Yes, it follows from connectedness. In fact you only need $D$ to be connected. Intuitively, the map $H_1(D') \to H_1(D', D)$ is surjective because a path in $D'$ with endpoints in $D$ can be closed up into a loop because $D$ is path-connected. One way to formalize this is to observe that you also have a long exact sequence in reduced homology, and then the relevant term is $\widetilde{H}_0(D) = 0$.

As for the result being deep: the results mentioned in my answer are the building blocks of Poincaré duality, which is something that might be considered deep or basic, depending on who you ask... In any case, there's probably a more elementary proof if you are willing to assume that the open sets in question are "nice" in some way, for instance if they are the interiors of compact submanifolds with boundary of $X$. But for arbitrary open sets, I don't see how to avoid using this machinery.

Ah so it's possibly simpler if one assumes that $D$ and $D'$ have smooth boundaries?

Yes, I imagine. One thing you can do in this case is compute $H_2(D', D)$ using excision. You still need to know that $H_2 = 0$ for a non-compact surface, but that's a bit easier than the argument in my answer. If you want to do a "geometric" proof that the map $H_1(D) \to H_1(D')$ is injective, you would try to prove that a null-homologous embedded loop in a surface is the boundary of a compact subsurface, and then derive a contradiction from that. But I'm not sure how to make this work.
